# Remove account without affecting the data

Tags: contacts, google-account

I have a phone with a Google account from an external provider (namely gazeta.pl). At one moment, due to policy reasons, the mail provider changed the platform from Google to proprietary system. So it's no longer a Google account.

I have all the contacts connected to this old account. The same situation with all the apps in the store. I can't log to it anymore via Google means. I have another regular gmail connected as well, I can install new apps, but cannot update anything (especially Google play services).

I need to have access to Play Store and update system. My best call is to remove the old account, but this will lead to losing all the contacts (SMS as well? I'm not sure). How to proceed without manually rewriting contacts? I would like to have them connected to my new gmail.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, the only problem you have is losing your contacts if you sign out of your Google Account.

First of all, your contacts on your Google Account can be accessed on 
[Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com), so signing out of your Google Account on your phone doesn't necessarily mean losing all of your contacts on that account.

Secondly, transferring contacts from one Gmail account to another is fairly easy, and you can find a step by step guide on how to do so [Here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/164640?hl=en)

Comment: I think I did not make my point clear. The old account is no longer a google account, so it's not accessible in any standardized way.

Comment: @PiotrZierhoffer If that's the case, then I'm at a loss, because I don't know how they would convert a Google account to something else.  I'm not sure if that's even possible.  Are you sure that's what happened?

Comment: Yes. As far as I know Google stopped providing the infrastructure for other companies, that allow open registration of emails in their domains. So while you still can have a corporate Google account, you can no longer create a service named, let's say, mario.com, providing Google account for the public. And that was the case of gazeta.pl.